# How can you add links, popup windows etc to layout in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-flow

I built some views that extend layouts from package `com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout`. The problem is there are a lot of useful stuff in package `com.vaadin.ui` like Link, PopupView etc that I can't add to my views. I tried making my view extend UI from `com.vaadin.ui` but that doesn't work, I get the following error:

> Failed to load the widgetset.

What is the best solution to my problem? How can I add the needed stuff to my view?
I have just started using Vaadin few days ago.

Comment: I can not find Link or PopupView in my Vaadin 13 project.  Are you mixing different major vaadin versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.vaadin.ui` is Vaadin 7 or Vaadin 8. `com.vaadin.flow` is Vaadin 10+. Those two cannot be used together unless you're using the commercial [multiplatform runtime](https://vaadin.com/multiplatform-runtime).

For `Link`, you can instead use the `Anchor` or `RouterLink` components. There isn't any direct replacement for `PopupView`, but it should be possible to assemble something similar by combining `Button` and `ContextMenu`. See https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/migration/5-components.html for a full overview of the relationship between components in the old and new versions of Vaadin.